# Folder Structure Name Match Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure in a directory called FTP.

```
\\FTP\December 15
\\FTP\January 15
\\FTP\February 15
\\FTP\March 15
```

etc...

I will be moving files to this folder using a powershell script: multiple files. potentially multiple folders.

I want to extract the month

```
$month = get-date -format m
```

This will return December

Now how do I write the GCI statement to match the folder to the month

For example: Something like this?

```
gci '\\FTP\' -recurse WHERE $_.Fullname -like $a.substring(0,9)
```

Please help

Comment: Are those all shares on a server called FTP? Don't think you can call those in PowerShell without first using `\\server\share` as part of `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: @Matt I simplified it for this question, but yes I use UNC paths. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$month = get-date -format m` returns `December 15` I assume that's correct.

Then your code will look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem \\FTP\ -recurse | where { $_.Fullname -like "*$month*"}
```

we use `Where-Object` which will return each item matching the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to get the month specific folder then you can do whatever you need by replacing the "Do Work To Said Folder" Comment with whatever you want to do to the folder.(Copy To, Get-ChildItems, etc.)

```
function Get-MonthlyFolder
{
$month = get-date -format m;
#Bellow Line Gets The Full Path To Current Monthly Folder Stored In $folderInst variable:
$folderInst = gci "\\FTP" | Where {$.Name -like "$month*"} | Select FullName;
#Do Work To Said Folder
}
Get-MonthlyFolder;
```